# Django: No module named 'app'

Tags: python, django, runtime-error

Django barfs with

```
ImportError at /store/
No module named store
```

But right there is the debug message there is the setting

```
INSTALLED_APPS = 
  ('django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.admindocs',
  'store')

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.4.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'store')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/paul/cs462/store/store/views.py" in main
  37.   return redirect(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  363.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  253.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  265.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  105.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named store
```

The shell works just fine (for what I try), but this error is displayed at every page I have. Doesn't having 'store' in the apps means that the module is imported???

EDIT: I've used Django for project many times. This was working a few hours ago. There is a blank `__init__.py` file in store/. Moreover, by using a print statement, I was able to determine that this gets executed (twice). `urls.py` and `models.py` also are executed (but not `views.py`). I have no idea what I could do to get this error.

Comment: Can you post complete trace.

Comment: No it doesn't mean it is imported: it means you want to import it. For this, the module must be in your python path. Please give more details on your directory structure and how you are starting your app.

Comment: How have you created `store` ? Is there a file named `__init__.py` inside `store` folder ?

Comment: Also, if your store app is organised into a separate apps folder, have you made sure that is on the python path (although I think the `__init__.py` might be the answer)?

Comment: how did you call the path?

Comment: perhaps an excerpt of the `view.py`?

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes. Typo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it were not for version control, I would have never found this. As it was, it took me almost an hour to track it down.

The mistake was in store/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('store.views',
    url(r'^$', 'main'),
    url(r'^new_delivery_user/$', 'new_delivery_user'),
    ...
    url(r'^event_signal/$', 'store.views.event_signal'), # problem
)
```

I had moved the last URL from the project url.py to this app-specific one, which used the shorthand 'store.views' for prepending each of the views.

It should have appeared:

```
    url(r'^event_signal/$', 'event_signal'),
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Paul Draper, after I changed the

```
re_path('api/(?P<version>(v1|v2))/', include('music.urls'))
```

into :

```
    re_path('api/(?P<version>(v1|v2))/', include('musicservices.music.urls'))
```

the problem resolved.