# django importerror no module named models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've read many issues like this but I can't figure out mine `No module named survatapp.models` :(

The file tree is like:

```
/survat         #theproject
    /survatapp  #theapp
        __init__.py
        views.py
        forms.py
        models.py
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/list/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'survat.survatapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis\survat\urls.py" in <module>
  4. import survat.survatapp.views
File "C:\Users\Milexjaro\Dropbox\Thesis\survat\survatapp\views.py" in <module>
  7. from survat.survatapp.models import Document

Exception Type: ImportError at /list/
Exception Value: No module named survatapp.models
```

Here is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from survat.survatapp.models import Document
from survat.survatapp.forms import DocumentForm

def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('survat.survatapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'survatapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
def validate_file_extension(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('.csv'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Error message')

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

UPDATE: There is `__init__.py` in `survat` I ran `django-admin.py startproject addressbook .` to build the project. So that's why I think there is `/survat/survatapp` instead of `/survat/survat/survatapp`. And when I changed `survat.survatapp` in INSTALLED_APPS into `survatapp` and changed all `survat.survatapp` to `survatapp` in views.py etc.,  I couldn't run the server, with error: `No module named survatapp` , I think my issue similiar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404580/django-no-module-named-app), and in my `survatapp/urls.py` be like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('survat.survatapp.views',
    url(r'^list/$', 'list', name='list'),
)
```

I think this is fine because I used `'list'` instead of `'survat.survatapp.views.list'` like [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404580/django-no-module-named-app)

NB: Everything fine back then, it could run smoothly, but when I tried to import `test.py` in `views.py`, it raised an error, then I deleted `test.py` and the import code in `views.py` and I stuck like this

UPDATE 6/3/2015 : added models.py

Comment: You should be able to add just `survatapp` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting

Comment: @Brandon and to only use `from survatapp import models` in the views...

Comment: Just a question: is there an `__init__.py` file in your `survat` directory ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Good catch - still drinking morning coffee :)

Comment: Django is looking for `models.py` in `/survat/survat/survatapp` so either use `from survatapp.models import [...]` or relative import `from .models import [...]`

Comment: can you post the contents of `models.py` file?

Comment: Thank for the answers bros @Brandon  , but seems it didn't work well :(