# Django Project Can't Find Models After Django 1.7 Upgrade

Tags: django, django-models

I've faced many hurdles in upgrading my Django 1.6.2 project to Django 1.8.4.  The latest problem which has me stumped is this one.  When I start my Django dev server and try to access my site, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named account.models

Traceback:
File "/Users/me/venv/myproj_dj_18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Users/me/venv/myproj_dj_18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/me/venv/myproj_dj_18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/me/venv/myproj_dj_18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/www/myproj/conf/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from apps.admin.views import all_admins
File "/www/myproj/apps/admin/views.py" in <module>
  27. from apps.account.models import Account
```

This is a portion of my project's folder structure:

```
myproj
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── account
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
├── conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
```

Here is a portion of my url file:

```
# conf/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib import admin
from apps.admin.views import all_admins

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^account/',            include('apps.account.urls')),
    url(r'^members/',            include('apps.members.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/all_admins/$',
        user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)(all_admins),
        {'template': 'all_admins.html'},
        name='all-admins'),
    url(r'^admin/review/queue/$',
        'apps.admin.views.review_queue',
        {'template': 'review_queue.html'},
        name='review-queue'),
    url(r'^admin/',              include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'',                     include('apps.home.urls')),
)
```

These are my installed apps:

```
# apps/conf/settings/base.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'apps.admin',
    'apps.account',
    'apps.home',
)
```

This is a portion of the model file:

```
# apps/account/models.py
from django.db import models
class Account(models.Model):
    pass
```

I've subclassed the new AppConfig class per the docs:

```
# apps/account/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.account'

# apps/account/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'apps.account.apps.AccountConfig'

# apps/admin/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MyAdminConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.admin'
    label = 'my_admin'
    verbose_name = 'Administration'

# apps/admin/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'apps.admin.apps.MyAdminConfig'
```

I've checked to ensure that all my paths are mutually consistent:

```
$ python
>>> from django.apps import apps as myproj_apps
>>> account = myproj_apps.get_app_config('account')
>>> account.name  # => 'apps.account'
>>> list(account.get_models())  # => [apps.account.models.Account]
```

I can also do this with no errors:

```
$ python
>>> from apps.account.models import Account
>>> Account.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I tried changing all paths described above from "apps.account.models" to "myproj.apps.account.models" but that didn't help.  I've also read the Django 1.7 Applications doc but don't see what I'm doing wrong.  Nothing has turned up in my web searches either.  This looks like something simple.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a problem with your urls.  Any chance you can show what you have in your urls.py file?

Comment: I've added part of my urls file...  Why do you think it's a url issue?

Comment: I think it may be urls because of 'no module named'.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404580/django-no-module-named-app

Comment: Are you able to import that module from `./manage.py shell` ?

Comment: Are you going to a specific url?  Because if not you don't currently have a #home url setup.   Do you get the same issue when you go to www.yoursite.com/admin/

Comment: I'm also wondering if it has anything to do with the label to my admin app which I've added above.  There was a naming class so I had to provide a new unique name for it.  I'll look right now at the other question you're pointing me to.  Yes, it's acting like it thinks account.models is the dotted path to a module directory that would contain an __init__.py file.

Comment: Yes, I can go into the shell and do "from apps.account.models import Account".  Yes, I do actually have a "home" url there.  I just took it out to keep things brief.  It's the default path and I'm adding it above.

Comment: I'm wondering if my having a top-level "apps" directory that contains my actual apps is confusing the new apps registry code.  The exception is "No module named account.models" and it's being triggered by the expression " from apps.account.models import Account" in my apps/admin/views.py file.